# Определение числа чисел с разными знаками

Tags: javascript

Необходимо написать функцию, которая определяет количество
положительных чисел, отрицательных чисел и нулей.

Пользователь подает на вход программы какое количество чисел будет вводить, затем
вводит сами числа.

Пример вывода:

```
Положительных: 2 шт.  
Отрицательных: 5 шт.  
Нулей: 3 шт.
```

Не могу понять куда задать Prompt

```
function str(num1, num2, num3) {

var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < num1.length; ++i) {
    if (num1[i] == +1) {}
    count++;
}
var test = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < num2.length; j++) {
    if (num2[i] == -1) {}
    test++;
}
var test2 = 0;
for (var p = 0; p < num3.length; p++) {
    if (num3[i] == 0) {

    }
    test2++;
}

document.write("Положительных"+' '+count  + '<br>' + 'Отрицательных'+' '+test  + '<br>' +'Нулей'+' '+ test2 );
}

str([], [], []);
```

Comment: Заводите 3 счетчика. Поочередно смотрите на каждое число, и увеличиваете на 1 тот или иной счетчик. Когда числа кончаются, выводите получившиеся значения. Как-то так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> function str(num1, num2, num3) {
> ```

```
function f(a) {
```

И все циклы по этому массиву.

> ```
> if (num1[i] == +1) {}
> count++;
> ```

```
if (a[i] > 0) count++;
```

или даже

```
count += a[i] > 0;
```

Для отрицательных аналогично.